# image text alignment, cross-browser-compatibility question

Tags: css, internet-explorer, safari, cross-browser

I'm having some cross-browser positioning problems. I've got a short bio element and I'd like for the .bio_name element to go over the image. Using the styles below, I've got it working in all prevalent browsers (those used in Adobe's Browserlab) except Safari 4.0, and IE 7 (in IE 8 it work great though). What changed from Safari 3 to Safari 4/IE 7 t0 IE 8?

[Example of error](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/nj7tzSTHZKINj3uSzOvJbA?feat=directlink)

I have a structure like this:

```
<div id="some_id" class="bio">  
<h3>  
<img src="http://www.hello.com/some.jpg" alt="blah" />  
<a name="person"></a>  
</h3>  
<div class="bio_info">  
<h3 class="bio_name">First Last</h3>  
blah  
<div class="add_bio">blah more</div>  
</div>  
<span class="add_bio_toggle">more</span>  
</div>
```

and it's styled like this:

```
 .bio{    
   position: relative;  
   min-height: 175px;  
   }  

.bio img{  
   float: left;  
   margin-right: 10px;  
   width: 160px;  
   height: 143px;  
   vertical-align:text-top;  
   margin-top:10px; align:left;  
   }  

  .bio_info{  
   margin-top: -40px;  
   }  

.bio_info h3{  
   line-height: -1px;    
   margin-top: 7px;  
   }  

.add_bio_toggle{  
   display: block;   
   cursor: pointer;  
   color: blue;  
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're creating these "bio elements" is not optimal.

Try this instead:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/xMGNf/show/light/) ([edit](http://jsfiddle.net/xMGNf/))

It looks consistent between IE7/8, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari.

**HTML:**

```
<a name="person">
<div id="some_id" class="bio">
    <h3 class="bio_name">First Last First Last First Last First Last</h3> 
    <div class="add_bio">
        <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" alt="blah" /> 
        <div>
            blah more
            <span class="add_bio_toggle">more</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.add_bio {
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: auto
}
.add_bio div {
    margin-left: 170px
}
.bio {
    margin-bottom: 16px
}
.bio img {  
   float: left;  
   width: 160px;  
   height: 143px;  
   margin: 10px 0 0 0;
   border: 1px solid red
}
.add_bio_toggle {
    display: block;
    margin: 12px 0 0 0
}
```